# Prove $6\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ 3 \end{Bmatrix}+6\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ 2 \end{Bmatrix}+ 3\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}=3^n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

> Prove $6\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ 3 \end{Bmatrix}+6\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ 2 \end{Bmatrix}+ 3\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}=3^n$

I need a combinatorial proof of this identity. The right hand side must be a sequence of length $n$ but I dont know how to link that to the left side? Note: $\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ k \end{Bmatrix}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind meaning it is the number of ways to partition $[n]$ into $k$ subsets.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers. Also, please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons.

Comment: What do  denote $\begin{Bmatrix}n\\ i\end{Bmatrix}$?

Comment: @Bernard stirling numbers of the second kind

Answer (score 1):

The three terms from left to right represent the number of ways to partition $n$ distinct items into $3$ distinct subsets, of which $3,2,1$ are non-empty respectively. The Stirling number counts the number of partitions into $3,2,1$ non-empty subsets and the $6$ or $3$ counts the number of distinct ways to permute the subsets. (For $1$ non-empty subset, the two empty subsets are identical, so we divide by $2$; otherwise all $3!=6$ permutations are distinct.)

The sum of these three terms is the number of ways to partition $n$ items into $3$ subsets without restrictions, which is equal to the RHS of $3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Putting Parcly's answer differently: To choose a function $[n]\to[3]$, we first choose the size $k$ of its range, then partition the inputs into $k$ nonempty groups, then assign a distinct value to each group.